# JS's play() in jQuery ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

Is there equivalent of JS's play() or pause() methods in jQuery ? I'm looking for jquery solutions but preferably no other plug-ins.

```
$('#play').click(function() { 
    function play() {  
      //  the same in jquery ?  
        document.getElementById('demo').play();
        document.getElementById('demo').volume = 1;       
    }
    function play_pause() { 
       //  the same in jquery ?
        document.getElementById('demo').pause();
        document.getElementById('demo').currentTime = 0;        
    }
    if ( $(this).val() === "play" ) {
       $(this).val("pause"); 
       play();
    } else {
       $(this).val("play");
      pause();
    } 
});
```

I need the simplest solution, not big fancy plugins please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the raw HTML element from jQuery like this;

```
$("#demo")[0].play();
```

You may also need to check if the demo element actually exists:

```
if($("#demo").length) $("#demo")[0].play();
```

So in your example, you would have:

```
$('#play').click(function() { 
    if ( $(this).val() === "play" ) {
       $(this).val("pause");
       $("#demo")[0].play();
       $("#demo")[0].volume = 1;
    } else {
       $(this).val("play")[0].pause();
       $("#demo")[0].pause();
       $("#demo")[0].currentTime = 0; 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Can I use this [0] for a particular instance, when I have say 10 audio tags of different instances ?

Comment: @Borislav Sure can. If you have 13 audio elements, you can use `$("#audio")[12]` to access the 13th element. Again though, you might want to check that there are *actually* 13 elements before trying to access it.

Comment: I will check it with each() and probably with some kind of [this]

Comment: If you are using `.each` don't forget that it contains an overload for the DOM element: `$("#audio").each(index, element) { element.play(); // Element is a DOM element, not a jQuery object });` :)